# NuxtのSSRデプロイについて

Tags: デプロイ, nuxt.js

お世話になります。

nuxtのSSRモードでのデプロイ方法、ご存知の方
おられましたらご教示お願いできますでしょうか？

まずは環境、諸々ですが

node: v8.12.0
nuxt: v2.3.1
パッケージマネージャー: yarn
Build: yarn create nuxt-appにて expressテンプレートを選択
ビルド後にnuxtを最新の2.3.1へアップデート

デプロイ先情報
GMOクラウドVPS
OS: CentOS 7.3.1611
node: v8.12.0

です。

デプロイ方法については、本家サイトの説明も含め
ネット上で情報を探せど
ちょっとした設定と
各々のPaaSが提供するCLIを叩いてデプロイしましょう
という情報は見つかりますが

肝心のそもそも、どこからどこまでの階層のディレクトリをデプロイすれば良いのか
という情報が全く見つかりません。

generateで書き出した静的ページ化されたデータは
dist直下のデータを全てデプロイすればそれで完結ですが

SSRの場合はどの様にすれば
デプロイ、リリースまでできるのでしょうか？

詳しい方おられましたらご教示頂けると有り難いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的にはVPSにデプロイする場合でもPaaSにデプロイする場合でも基本的な部分は変わりません。

構成は条件によって多々あるでしょうが、一般的には

(プロジェクトのルートディレクトリをgitで管理してるとして)

- gitでプロジェクトを丸々サーバー上に配置し
- デプロイ時に`yarn install`
- アセットのビルド(`yarn build`)等をし
- サーバープロセス(expres等)の再起動

といったところでしょうか。

(アセットのビルドについては別でやって放り込んでもいいのですが)

サーバー上に配置するのはpushでもpullでも構いませんが(一般にはpullでしょうが)、プロジェクト上の`.gitignore`でignoreされていないファイルは基本的に必要と思っておけば大丈夫です。

直接expressで80や443でlistenしても構いませんが、一般には [nginx proxy - Nuxt.js](https://ja.nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy) あたりを参考にnginxででリバプロするなどすることになるかと。
また、expressのサーバープロセスを永続化、自動再起動するために[pm2](https://pm2.io/)などで起動することに……

---

デプロイやプロセス管理面倒なら結局Dokkuとか入れて任せたほうが早いかもしれませんが。

Comment: 大変、貴重な情報をありがとうございます。

Comment: いくつか、自分で調べてはいましたが
サーバープロセスの永続化、自動再起動の方法については
まだ、調べられていなかったので大変助かりました。
ありがとうございます。

Dokkuの件も大変ありがたいです。
次の機会にはぜひ試してみたいと思います！